# JS Form Validation produces no result

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am going through the lessons on CodeAcademy and am trying to create a simple HTML form validating the input fields with JS.  It's the beginning of a pet project for my brother's business (he needs his website completely rebuilt).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email Form</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="email-form" action="#">
        <input type='text' name="firstname" value="First Name" onsubmit="return validateForm();"><br>
        <input type='text' name='email' value="Email"><br>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Get AMPed!'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS script:

```
function validateForm() {
    var fName = document.email-form.firstname.value;
    if (fName == null || fName == "") {
        alert("Please provide your first name!");
        fName.firstname.focus();
        return false;
    }

    var fEmail = document.email-form.email.value;
    var atPos = fEmail.indexOf("@");
    var dotPos = fEMail.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atPos < 1 || dotPos < atPos + 2 || dotPos + 2 >= fEmail.length) {
        alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've tried to by "return validateForm();" by using onclick= on the 'submit' button but that wasn't working either.

Any help would be spectacularly awesome to someone who is really trying to learn the right way.

Comment: Where is return true ?

Comment: I think it's `email-form` what causes trouble. You can't use "-" in identifiers. It gets interpreted as a calculation (email - form). Use `email_form` as the name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with this code. The idea behind it is right, although your function throws a couple of errors, which results in an interruption of the function, meaning that it won't return anything.

**Identifiers must not contain the character "-" (minus).** It is reserved for subtraction. You cannot use it in identifiers. The expression `document.email-form.firstname.value` gets interpreted as a calculation. It tries to subtract `form.firstname.value` from `document.email`. Both of these don't exist which results in a *ReferenceError*.

Instead of the minus character, use an underscore, which you can safely use in identifiers. Change the forms name from `email-form` to `email_form`.

**`fName.firstname.focus()` does not exist.** `fName` is a string (the content of the text input). What you actually want to do is `document.email_form.firstname.focus()`.

**Your function should always return a value.** Therefore, you should `return true` at the very end of it. This is not neccessary, but it contributes to the readability of your code.

Once you fixed all those things, you can either use `onClick="return validateForm()"` on your button or `onSubmit="return validateForm()"` on the form.

Comment: I know this is a late response, but thank you for your detailed answer. After coming back to this problem months later I can now see the mistakes I made.

Comment: @StefanP.DiBella This was unexpected. But still glad to help :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `document.email-form` will not work, you need to use it this way: `document['email-form']`. (Because `-` will cause an arithmetic calculation)

Try to use the debug tools of your browser, and you would see the error messages..

Secondly, use `onsubmit="return validateForm();"` in your `<form>` tag, not your `<input>` tag.